# Google Insights Performance measurements for Desktop

Tags: pagespeed-insights

In the Google Insights about page (https://developers.google.com/speed/docs/insights/v5/about)
It mentions that Google emulates a Moto G4 mobile device to measure page performance.  What does Google use for desktop to measure page performance?